# Does SQL Server 2008R2 Express come with the reporting services?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I can't find any reference anywhere to it. If so, how do I enable it and access it? The only application that I could find that was related was the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

If Express does come with it, how do I activate and use it? Does anyone know any good tutorials>?

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services to have also Reporting Services (it is not clear to me why but I can see only RTM version in microsoft downloads right now)